# How to distinguish response validation error from other validation errors in Elysia.js

Tags: bun, elysiajs

I would like to validate response of request in silent (for example only log to console) because I don't want to interrupt user with this information (also response schema is used in elysiajs swagger plugin so it is useful to have it), but I still want to know when this happens. Also I want to validate body strictly and return 400.

This is far as I got, I can use onError and catch an error, but can't differentiate between body validation and response validation.

```js
import { Elysia, t } from "elysia";

export const PostLoginRoute = new Elysia()
  .onError((error) => {
    console.log("error", error);
    return new Response(error.toString());
  })
  .post("/login", ({ body }) => body, {
    body: t.Object(
      {
        username: t.String(),
        password: t.String(),
      },
      {
        description: "Expected an username and password",
      }
    ),
    response: t.Object({
      username: t.String(),
      password: t.String(),
      id: t.String(),
    }),

    detail: {
      summary: "Sign in the user",
      tags: ["authentication"],
    },
  });
```

error content

```
error: Invalid response, 'id': Expected string

Expected: {
  "username": "",
  "password": "",
  "id": ""
}

Found: {
  "username": "user",
  "password": "pass"
}
 code: "VALIDATION"

      at new K0 (/hi-elysia/node_modules/elysia/dist/bun/index.js:8:25881)
,
  set: {
    headers: {},
    status: 500
  },
  code: "VALIDATION"
}
```

I can parse message of error and find `Invalid response` substring, but I kind of dislike this idea. Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it.

```js
onError(({ error, code, set }) => {
  switch (code) {
    // Other cases...
    
    case "VALIDATION": {
      if (error.type === "response") {
        set.status = "Internal Server Error";

        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
          return error.message;
        }

        return { error: "Server validation error" }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I have this as a global error middleware, but you can also attach it directly to a specific route. The case will be `VALIDATION` both when the **request** body is invalid and when the **response** body is invalid. You can check whether it's request or response with `error.type` after narrowing down the type on `code`.

Here, I've set the status code to be 500 if the validation error happened on the server output, because default code for any validation error is 400 (bad request), but I consider it a server error if I didn't properly respond according to the schema. I'm also omitting some details when running in production.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page: https://elysiajs.com/patterns/error-handling.html

There is an example showing exactly how to do that.

In short, add local error handler, *switch* on an error code, than map through errors looking into *path* property.

```
new Elysia()
.post('/', ({ body }) => body, {
    body: t.Object({
        name: t.String(),
        age: t.Number()
    }),
    error({ code, error }) {
        switch (code) {
            case 'VALIDATION':
                console.log(error.all)

                // Find a specific error name (path is OpenAPI Schema compliance)
                const name = error.all.find((x) => x.path === '/name')

                // If has validation error, then log it
                if(name)
                    console.log(name)
        }
    }
})
```

X - is an object containing info you need.

Something like this:

```
E {
  type: 53,
  schema: {
    type: "string",
    [Symbol(TypeBox.Kind)]: "String"
  },
  path: "/name",
  value: undefined,
  message: "Expected string"
}
```

Comment: I need to distinguish between input(body, query, params) and output (response) validation, but both have code VALIDATION

Comment: Take a look at this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sinclair/typebox. It is used by elysia to validate schemes.
You could describe schema for body, query and params differenttly and distinguish between them using TypeGuard.